# Passing on Rails model to child controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I have the following url  `/purchases/3/payments/new`, which I get in the purchases controller by

```
link_to 'pay', purchase_path(purchase)+new_payment_path
```

Now in the payments controller I would need to have the purchase object, or its id at least from where it was invoked.
I tried using a param, but is there any other way ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using params makes sense.

You should be able to get the purchase ID like this in the payments controller:

```
params[:purchase_id]
```

However, need to setup your routes in a specific way to do this:

```
resources :purchases do
  resources :payments
end
```

Then you can create the link in the view like this:

```
link_to 'pay', new_purchase_payment_path(purchase)
```

Have a look at these docs too: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: I tried that. but seems param is not getting there.

Answer (score 0):

**Routes**

I immediately highlighted this as a problem:

```
 purchase_path(purchase)+new_payment_path
```

This is really bad (configuration over convention) - you'll be much better using the actual path helper to load the resource you need (keeps it DRY & conventional)

--

**Nested**

As mentioned by `Jon M`, your solution will come from the use of [`nested resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :purchases do
    resources :payments  # -> domain.com/purchases/:purchase_id/payments/new
end
```

This will allow you to use the route path as described by `Jon`.

--

**Controller**

> in the payments controller I would need to have the purchase object,
>   or its id

By using nested resources, as described above, the route will hit your `payments` controller and have the following `param` available:

```
params[:purchase_id]
```

*Note* the naming of the param (only the `nested` resource is identified with `params[:id]`), as demonstrated [in the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources): `/magazines/:magazine_id/ads/:id`

I would recommend using the following code in your controller:

```
#app/controllers/payments_controller.rb
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @purchase = Purchase.find params[:purchase_id]
   end
end
```